# CVS checkout: Checking out project to a directory other than the one you are currently in?

Tags: cvs, vcs-checkout

Currently I issue the following command:  cvs -d /path/cvsroot checkout -P directory/powers_npg/

However, this checks out the entire directory structure that is above the directory to the location I am in when I issue this command.

I am trying to check out this tree, but I want it checked out to a different directory than my PWD.

I would like something like this command:

cvs -d /wv/path/cvsroot checkout -P directory/powers_npg/ /home/me/Desktop/

So whatever would be checked out to my current location would be checked out to /home/me/Desktop/ instead.

I am accomplishing this right now by having a script that just moves the tree when I'm done checking out, but I imagine there's a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want is the -d option to cvs checkout, something like

```
cvs checkout -d place-you-want-it module
```

From the CVS man page in "checkout options":

> -d dir
>
> Create a directory called dir for the
>   working files, instead of using the
>   module name.  In general, using  this 
>   flag is equivalent to using mkdir dir;
>   cd dir followed by the checkout
>   command without the -d flag.

Example:

```
$ cvs checkout -d /stuff/cvs/baz -P baz/another
cvs checkout: Updating /stuff/cvs/baz
U /stuff/cvs/baz/some
$ ls /stuff/cvs/baz
CVS/  some
$
```

Comment: ORder matters: `-d dir module` works, `module -d dir` does not.

Comment: The order strictly matters.